# Passing VPN connection to VM from Hyper V

Tags: windows, vpn, virtual-machines, hyper-v

So this may be an odd and impossible request.

The company I work for has a setup where we use VM's on Hyper V. However, some of our VM's require to be connected to a VPN so that a client can access them. This isn't really an issue except for the fact that we need to setup new VPN credentials for every new VM we setup for them.

What I was wondering was if it was possible for us to setup the VPN connection on the Host and then pass this VPN connection through to the VM's as a Virtual Switch?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are aware that you can have a VM acting as router (I do that, using Mikrotik CHR as router) and then route to the internal vm's by whatever means you think are appropriate?

Comment: @TomTom No... I wasn't aware. And I'm not quite sure I am still any the wiser!